can we load 3rd party script- GTM, pixel,hotjar,salesiq,poptin through service worker?
I am working on performance optimization of my static site, When generating audit reports through Page speed insights , I am getting 90%+ overall performance but when injecting 3rd third-party script in standard pattern with async, overall performance is reducing up to 40%.
Techstack what I am using are HTML, Vite, Tailwind, swiper, and nginx
you can check performance reports with and without 3rd party script here :
Performance with 3rd party scripts
Performance Without 3rd party scripts 

I have tried Caching, and minifying my code and assets.
I have used generating Assets file names with hash
I have already optimized my images
I have preloaded images which is required to load FCP, and using lazy loading for the rest of the images which is not required in the landing viewport

To solve this I was thinking of implementing service workers.
Is that a good idea to do so?
How can we do this?
or
Any additional hack we have to inject 3rd party script?
Note: Can't manipulate GTM, as the same GTM is injecting in WordPress and performance is Quite good approx 90%+.
